# Manipulating two dataframes to arrive at the output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on this code for quite a while but could not get to the output.
I have two dataframes which look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 3,'Sales', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'],['B',5 ,'Sales', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],['C', 4,'FIN', 'Y', 'N', 'N'],['D', 2,'FIN', 'N', 'Y', 'Y']],
                          columns=['EMP_NAME', 'HOURS', 'DEPT', 'COM', 'OT', 'BIN'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['COM','SALES', 0.05, 5],['OT','SALES', 0.02, 2],['BIN','SALES', 0.02, 3],['COM','FIN', 0.06, 0], ['OT','FIN', 0.04, 6], ['BIN','FIN', 0.07, 8]],
                          columns=['CATEGORY','DEPT', 'RATE', 'EXTRA'])
```

The task is to calculate the total amount for all the employees who have 'Y'
in the columns 'Com', 'OT', 'BN' in df1 using the data in df2. For instance, for Employee A, the amount for OT would be 3 (Hours) * 0.04 (Rate) + 2 (Extra). That means, find the corresponding rate for Category 'OT' with Dept 'SALES' in df2 and calculate the amount as shown above.  Finally, all the 'Y's have to be replaced by their respective amounts in df1.  I tried using join and many other approaches but none seemed to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
cols = ["COM", "OT", "BIN"]


def fn(x):
    out = []

    for c in cols:
        if x[c] == "Y":
            rate, extra = df2.loc[
                df2.CATEGORY.eq(c) & df2.DEPT.eq(x.DEPT.upper()),
                ["RATE", "EXTRA"],
            ].values[0]
            out.append(x.HOURS * rate + extra)
        else:
            out.append(0)

    return pd.Series(dict(zip(cols, out)))


df1.loc[:, cols] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
  EMP_NAME  HOURS   DEPT   COM    OT   BIN
0        A      3  Sales  0.00  2.06  3.06
1        B      5  Sales  0.00  0.00  3.10
2        C      4    FIN  0.24  0.00  0.00
3        D      2    FIN  0.00  6.08  8.14
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort.  Could you tell me what .values[0] does here